# When start start Elastic 8.01, we got a error

Tags: elasticsearch

We use 8.01. When start we got this error.  Any ideas what the issue is?

```
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2023-04-06 08:55:26 UTC; 27s ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
   Main PID: 4001020 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
        CPU: 16.276s

Apr 06 08:55:21 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Apr 06 08:55:26 ubuntu systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Apr 06 08:55:26 ubuntu systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Apr 06 08:55:26 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
Apr 06 08:55:26 ubuntu systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Consumed 16.276s CPU time.
```

Comment: Could we ask you to provide the logs ?

Comment: the logfile has to many characters to post in SO. Wich part you must see?

Comment: Hopefully the part that contains errors